# PHP Unknown Modifier

Tags: php, regex

Have trouble with this and have looked back at previous answers but still
seem not to be getting it. Here is the code:

```
preg_replace('/^.*"([http|https]://test.co/v/.*)/embed.*width=".*$/', '$1', $str);
```

Am getting a Unknown modifier '/' error.

Looking at the previous answers it looks like I have to deliminate the / that is
used in the query so I added a ~ before each forward slash but still the same
error. Am guessing I didn't quite understand it... any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: You're delimiting your pattern with `/`, then using `/` within the pattern itself. so `/^...https]:/` is the start and end of your pattern, and everything else after that point is a modifier and outside of the pattern.

Comment: You should also change `[http|https]` to `(http|https)` and change `test.co` to `test\.co` or `test[.]co`.

Comment: Thanks for your help and replies! Yes the question was similar to previous ones - as I mentioned I had read them but was still have difficulties implementing it on this particular code. All resolved now thankfully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Escape the `/` in the regex as

```
preg_replace('/^.*"((?:http|https):\/\/test\.co\/v\/.*)\/embed.*width=".*$/', '$1', $str);
```

**OR**

You can use a different delimter eg `#`

```
preg_replace('#^.*"((?:http|https:)//test\.co/v/.*)/embed.*width=".*$#', '$1', $str);
```

**Note**

- You can shorten `http|https` as `https?`
- Escape the `.` in `.co` as `\.co`

Comment: Thanks very much for your help - much appreciated and apologies for the slow reply! The person who wrote it left several other mistakes which was a problem but your help resolved this one.